# How to automatically select an already existing file in a directory

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

I am trying to replicate the standard save file process where, if there already exists a file with the necessary file extension, it is pre-selected in the `SaveFileDialog`. In my program I am using `SaveFileDialog` to allow the user to select the path for the file on the system. Upon save, it will automatically open to the path that the last saved file was, but the user has to re-select it.

Here is where I think something like this would come into play in my code:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = ".cct"; //The file extension

Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog(); //Lets user select path
//**I'm guessing that the "pre-select" operation I am talking about
//would go here
directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(dlg.FileName); //Directory = File path on system
```

I have looked at the `CheckFileExists` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.checkfileexists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it says that it "Gets or sets a value indicating whether a file dialog displays a warning if the user specifies a file name that does not exist." So it looks like it's more focused around checking whether or not the user enters a new file name.

**How do I make it so that the previously saved file with the same extension is highlighted or selected in the `SaveFileDialog` if one is found upon save?**

Comment: I believe you supply it as property of that dialog *before* displaying: `dlg.FileName=thatFileNameYouWantToBeSelectedByDefault`.

Comment: But how do I do that if I only know the extension and not the name (because it is picked by the user)?

Comment: Obviously, save *previously saved file* name somehow.

Comment: That would work, but what if you could just highlight the file with the equivalent extension?

Comment: You would have to do some leg work and know the directory already. Are you actually just talking about filtering the extensions? Look into the `Filter` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a couple of things.

- You could restore the path the user last saved with by setting `dlg.RestoreDirectory = true`.
- Set the `FileName` before you show the dialog and it will automatically show that folder and insert the file name using `dlg.FileName`

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)